# camel jpa @Consumed is not being called

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to use @Consumed on jpa entity with camel.

this is my route :

```
<route id="incomingFileHandlerRoute"> 
<from
   uri="jpa://com.menora.inbal.incomingFileHandler.Jpa.model.MessageToDB?consumer.nativeQuery=select
    * from file_message where mstatus = 'TODO'&amp;consumer.delay=5000&amp;consumeDelete=false&amp;consumeLockEntity=true&amp;consumer.SkipLockedEntity=true" />
<to uri="bean:incomingFileHandler" />
                    </route>
```

and my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file_message")
public class MessageToDB implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String uuid;
    private String fileName;
    private String body;
    private String mstatus;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date mtimestamp;

    @Consumed
    public void updateMstatus() {
        setMstatus(MessageStatus.DONE.name());
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getMstatus() {
        return mstatus;
    }

    public void setMstatus(String mstatus) {
        this.mstatus = mstatus;
    }

    public Date getMtimestamp() {
        return mtimestamp;
    }

    public void setMtimestamp(Date mtimestamp) {
        this.mtimestamp = mtimestamp;
    }

}
```

I do get to incomingFileHandler bean with results from db but I do not get to the Consumed method updateMstatus . The incomingFileHandler bean is getting called continuously as always there are results from db

Comment: Just an observation: The option `consumer.SkipLockedEntity` should be in lower-case Skip, eg `consumer.skipLockedEntity`

Comment: What version of Camel do you use, and what does your route do next? Maybe try with a simple route that just do from -> log. Also you can try set a breakpoint in the `@Consumed` method and see if its called, or add some logging there etc.

Comment: I am using 2.19.1 . I had put breakpoint in the @Consumed method and it is not being called . I removed the consumer.SkipLockedEntity - it did not change

Comment: I edit the route : <to uri="bean:incomingFileHandler" />

Comment: Maybe your bean causes an exception. Try to debug that part also.

Comment: I have no exception . it seems there is no effect of the org.apache.camel.component.jpa annotation in the entity - also @PreConsumed is not being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar implementation with camel-jpa and annotations `@Consumed` and `@PreConsumed` in the entity but none of these methods is called.

I look the camel-jpa source code and found this in **JpaConsumer.java**:

```
protected DeleteHandler<Object> createPreDeleteHandler() {
    // Look for @PreConsumed to allow custom callback before the Entity has been consumed
    final Class<?> entityType = getEndpoint().getEntityType();
    if (entityType != null) {
        // Inspect the method(s) annotated with @PreConsumed
```

if `entityType` is `null` the entity class inst inspect the method annotated with `@Consumed` and `@PreConsumed`.

**Solution:** add `entityType=com.xx.yy.MessageToDB` to your URI to set Endpoint Entity type.

Comment: but why should it be null ? I see in documentation : entityType
entityClassName
Overrides the entityClassName from the URI.

Comment: What I said is that it can not be null.

Comment: yes but I don't understand when it will be null ? I am sending it in my code : jpa://com.menora.inbal.incomingFileHandler.Jpa.model.MessageToDB

Comment: You must change to : jpa://com.menora.inbal.incomingFileHandler.Jpa.model.Message‌​ToDB?entityType=com.menora.inbal.incomingFileHandler.Jpa.model.Message‌​ToDB&.....

Comment: yes ok , but this is strange as the documentation  doesn't say this

Comment: You're right. I only discovered this when debugging camel-jpa code.

Comment: thank you very much @PauloRamos, your suggestion worked.  To me this looks like either a camel bug or incorrect documentation.